# project of reading file,counting each letter,evaluating the percentage of each letter

Tags: python

I tried these codes but they are \ not working properly.It is showing the file in vertical lines and not showing the percentages properly what do I have to do for it?I just did what our teacher asked us but its not working.

```
def CharCount(): #Defines function
CharCountA=0 #Initialises character counters' in this case character A
CharCountB=0
CharCountC=0
CharCountD=0
CharCountE=0
CharCountF=0
CharCountG=0
CharCountH=0
CharCountI=0
CharCountJ=0
CharCountK=0
CharCountL=0
CharCountM=0
CharCountN=0
CharCountO=0
CharCountP=0
CharCountQ=0
CharCountR=0
CharCountS=0
CharCountT=0
CharCountU=0
CharCountV=0
CharCountW=0
CharCountX=0
CharCountY=0
CharCountZ=0
TotalChars=0 #Initialises Total counters
InPath="C:\\_ATemp\\PlainTextMessage.txt" #Specify the location of files
OutPath="C:\\_ATemp\\Report.txt"
input=file(InPath, "r") #Defines the pointers to files 
output=file(OutPath,"w")
for line in file(InPath): #Extract a line from the file PlainMessageText.txt
    index=0
    while index<len(line): #Travese a line as a string from the file PlainMessageText.txt 
        char=line[index]
        print char
        if char=='a' or char=='A': #Test for the characters in this case character 'a' or 'A'
            CharCountA=CharCountA+1 #Adds 1 to character count in this case character A
        if char=='b' or char=='B':
            CharCountB=CharCountB+1
        if char=='c' or char=='C':
            CharCountC=CharCountC+1
        if char=='d' or char=='D':
            CharCountD=CharCountD+1
        if char=='e' or char=='E':
            CharCountE=CharCountE+1
        if char=='f' or char=='F':
            CharCountF=CharCountF+1
        if char=='g' or char=='G':
            CharCountG=CharCountG+1
        if char=='h' or char=='H':
            CharCountH=CharCountH+1
        if char=='i' or char=='I':
            CharCountI=CharCountI+1
        if char=='j' or char=='J':
            CharCountJ=CharCountJ+1
        if char=='k' or char=='K':
            CharCountK=CharCountK+1
        if char=='l' or char=='L':
            CharCountL=CharCountL+1
        if char=='m' or char=='M':
            CharCountM=CharCountM+1
        if char=='n' or char=='N':
            CharCountN=CharCountN+1
        if char=='o' or char=='O':
            CharCountO=CharCountO+1
        if char=='p' or char=='P':
            CharCountP=CharCountP+1
        if char=='q' or char=='Q':
            CharCountQ=CharCountQ+1
        if char=='r' or char=='R':
            CharCountR=CharCountR+1
        if char=='s' or char=='S':
            CharCountS=CharCountS+1
        if char=='t' or char=='T':
            CharCountT=CharCountT+1
        if char=='u' or char=='U':
            CharCountU=CharCountU+1
        if char=='v' or char=='V':
            CharCountV=CharCountV+1
        if char=='w' or char=='W':
            CharCountW=CharCountW+1
        if char=='x' or char=='X':
            CharCountX=CharCountX+1
        if char=='y' or char=='Y':
            CharCountY=CharCountY+1
        if char=='z' or char=='Z':
            CharCountZ=CharCountZ+1
                TotalChars=TotalChars+1
        index=index+1 #Moves pointer within the line by 1
    print len(line) #
print "Count of the letter A is ", CharCountB,"\t",float(CharCountB)/TotalChars*100
    print >> output, "Count of the letter A is ", CharCountB,"\t",float(CharCountB)/TotalChars*100
    print "Count of the letter B is ", CharCountB,"\t",float(CharCountB)/TotalChars*100
    print >> output, "Count of the letter B is ", CharCountB,"\t",float(CharCountB)/TotalChars*100
    print "Count of the letter C is ", CharCountC,"\t",float(CharCountC)/TotalChars*100
    print >> output, "Count of the letter C is ", CharCountC,"\t",float(CharCountC)/TotalChars*100
    print "Count of the letter D is ", CharCountD,"\t",float(CharCountD)/TotalChars*100
    print >> output, "Count of the letter D is ", CharCountD,"\t",float(CharCountD)/TotalChars*100
    print "Count of the letter E is ", CharCountE,"\t",float(CharCountE)/TotalChars*100
    print >> output, "Count of the letter E is ", CharCountE,"\t",float(CharCountE)/TotalChars*100
    print "Count of the letter F is ", CharCountF,"\t",float(CharCountF)/TotalChars*100
    print >> output, "Count of the letter F is ", CharCountF,"\t",float(CharCountF)/TotalChars*100
    print "Count of the letter G is ", CharCountG,"\t",float(CharCountG)/TotalChars*100
    print >> output, "Count of the letter G is ", CharCountG,"\t",float(CharCountG)/TotalChars*100
    print "Count of the letter H is ", CharCountH,"\t",float(CharCountH)/TotalChars*100
    print >> output, "Count of the letter H is ", CharCountH,"\t",float(CharCountH)/TotalChars*100
    print "Count of the letter I is ", CharCountI,"\t",float(CharCountI)/TotalChars*100
    print >> output, "Count of the letter I is ", CharCountI,"\t",float(CharCountI)/TotalChars*100
    print "Count of the letter J is ", CharCountJ,"\t",float(CharCountJ)/TotalChars*100
    print >> output, "Count of the letter J is ", CharCountJ,"\t",float(CharCountJ)/TotalChars*100
    print "Count of the letter K is ", CharCountK,"\t",float(CharCountK)/TotalChars*100
    print >> output, "Count of the letter K is ", CharCountK,"\t",float(CharCountK)/TotalChars*100
    print "Count of the letter L is ", CharCountL,"\t",float(CharCountL)/TotalChars*100
    print >> output, "Count of the letter L is ", CharCountL,"\t",float(CharCountL)/TotalChars*100
    print "Count of the letter M is ", CharCountM,"\t",float(CharCountM)/TotalChars*100
    print >> output, "Count of the letter M is ", CharCountM,"\t",float(CharCountM)/TotalChars*100
    print "Count of the letter N is ", CharCountN,"\t",float(CharCountN)/TotalChars*100
    print >> output, "Count of the letter N is ", CharCountN,"\t",float(CharCountN)/TotalChars*100
    print "Count of the letter O is ", CharCountO,"\t",float(CharCountO)/TotalChars*100
    print >> output, "Count of the letter O is ", CharCountO,"\t",float(CharCountO)/TotalChars*100
    print "Count of the letter P is ", CharCountP,"\t",float(CharCountP)/TotalChars*100
    print >> output, "Count of the letter P is ", CharCountP,"\t",float(CharCountP)/TotalChars*100
    print "Count of the letter Q is ", CharCountQ,"\t",float(CharCountQ)/TotalChars*100
    print >> output, "Count of the letter Q is ", CharCountQ,"\t",float(CharCountQ)/TotalChars*100
    print "Count of the letter R is ", CharCountR,"\t",float(CharCountR)/TotalChars*100
    print >> output, "Count of the letter R is ", CharCountR,"\t",float(CharCountR)/TotalChars*100
    print "Count of the letter S is ", CharCountS,"\t",float(CharCountS)/TotalChars*100
    print >> output, "Count of the letter S is ", CharCountS,"\t",float(CharCountS)/TotalChars*100
    print "Count of the letter T is ", CharCountT,"\t",float(CharCountT)/TotalChars*100
    print >> output, "Count of the letter T is ", CharCountT,"\t",float(CharCountT)/TotalChars*100
    print "Count of the letter U is ", CharCountU,"\t",float(CharCountU)/TotalChars*100
    print >> output, "Count of the letter U is ", CharCountL,"\t",float(CharCountU)/TotalChars*100
    print "Count of the letter V is ", CharCountV,"\t",float(CharCountV)/TotalChars*100
    print >> output, "Count of the letter V is ", CharCountV,"\t",float(CharCountV)/TotalChars*100
    print "Count of the letter W is ", CharCountW,"\t",float(CharCountW)/TotalChars*100
    print >> output, "Count of the letter W is ", CharCountL,"\t",float(CharCountW)/TotalChars*100
    print "Count of the letter X is ", CharCountX,"\t",float(CharCountX)/TotalChars*100
    print >> output, "Count of the letter X is ", CharCountX,"\t",float(CharCountX)/TotalChars*100
    print "Count of the letter Y is ", CharCountY,"\t",float(CharCountY)/TotalChars*100
    print >> output, "Count of the letter Y is ", CharCountY,"\t",float(CharCountY)/TotalChars*100
    print "Count of the letter Z is ", CharCountZ,"\t",float(CharCountZ)/TotalChars*100
    print >> output, "Count of the letter Z is ", CharCountZ,"\t",float(CharCountZ)/TotalChars*100
    print "Count of Total Characters is", TotalChars
    print >> output, "Count of Total Characters is ", TotalChars
```

Comment: As a general rule of thumb: if you are repeating yourself very often in your code, then you should try another way. Let the program handle similar cases, not the programmer. In your case, have a look at [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Comment: + What other comments can I add to these codes?

Comment: First of all, please read [ask]. In your case, specify what "not working properly" means. What output does your code produce, what should it produce? If it gives you an error message and a traceback, add this to your question. A first look shows that your function body should be indented one level deeper than `def CharCount(): #Defines function`.

Answer (score 0):

So here's how I would actually write this program:

```
# Allows us to get a list of a-z.
import string
# Allows us to use an OrderedDict.
import collections

# Creates an OrderedDict (like a normal dict but maintains key order),
# with the keys a-z and the starting values of 0.
total_counts = collections.OrderedDict().fromkeys(list(string.ascii_lowercase),0)
# Counter for totally number of characters.
total_chars = 0

# Opens the file "file.txt" from the same directory as the script.
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    # Processes it line by line.
    for line in f:
        # Removes captialization.
        line = line.lower()
        # Processes each character in line.
        for c in line:
            # Checks if c is in a-z (and not say a space or puncutation).
            if c in total_counts:
                # Adds count to the specific character and the overall number.
                total_counts[c] += 1
                total_chars += 1

# Iterates the OrderdDict and prints the percentage.
for character, count in total_counts.iteritems():
    print("Count of the letter " + character + " is " + str(count) + "\t" + str(float(count)/total_chars*100))
```

As you can see, I'm not writing `if` and `print` statements for every letter, but rather using loops to minimize the code required.

Most lines are commented, but if you have any questions let me know.

Also I wrote this in Python3 and converted it back to Python2.* (which I believe is what you're using), so their might be slight errors.